# How to fetch Firebase Real-time data into flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, android-sensors

How can I fetch sensor data from the Firebase Realtime database and display it in the Flutter app not in a List view?
My Database looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxrS4.png)

I want to display Temp1 and Temp2 data in two fields in the flutter app.

I tried using streambuilder but still couldn't get fetch the data.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include the code you have tried so far. Also, please take a second to read [ask]